# Does Android LazyVerticalGrid support swipe to dismiss

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my latest Android compose project I had swipe to dismiss working fine for LazyColumn.

I have now made a refactor and replaced all my LazyColumns with LazyVerticalGrids.

Everything works as expected with LazyVerticalGrid apart from swipe to dismiss

when I swipe an item from my LazyVerticalGrid with one column it works fine

However when i swipe an item from my LazyVerticalGrid with multiple columns it throws the following exception:-

```
Process: com.elsevier.practiceupdate, PID: 23783
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed requirement.
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.getLineIndexOfItem--_Ze7BM(LazyGridSpanLayoutProvider.kt:174)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemPlacementAnimatorKt.lastIndexInPreviousLineBefore(LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.kt:489)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemPlacementAnimatorKt.access$lastIndexInPreviousLineBefore(LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.kt:1)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.calculateExpectedOffset-xfIKQeg(LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.kt:370)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.onMeasured(LazyGridItemPlacementAnimator.kt:160)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridMeasureKt.measureLazyGrid-0cYbdkg(LazyGridMeasure.kt:241)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridKt$rememberLazyGridMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyGrid.kt:334)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyGridKt$rememberLazyGridMeasurePolicy$1$1.invoke(LazyGrid.kt:184)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$1$2$1.invoke-0kLqBqw(LazyLayout.kt:71)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutKt$LazyLayout$1$2$1.invoke(LazyLayout.kt:69)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1.measure-3p2s80s(SubcomposeLayout.kt:591)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(InnerNodeCoordinator.kt:103)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:578)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$2.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:577)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke-3p2s80s(AndroidOverscroll.kt:562)
    at androidx.compose.foundation.AndroidOverscrollKt$StretchOverscrollNonClippingLayer$1.invoke(AndroidOverscroll.kt:561)
    at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutModifierImpl.measure-3p2s80s(LayoutModifier.kt:285)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier.measure-3p2s80s(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:578)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.BackwardsCompatNode.measure-3p2s80s(BackwardsCompatNode.kt:343)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.measure-BRTryo0(LayoutModifierNodeCoordinator.kt:155)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1090)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate$performMeasure$2.invoke(LayoutNodeLayoutDelegate.kt:1086)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:130)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver$observeReads$1$1.invoke(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:341)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source:1)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:126)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:120)
    at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeMeasureSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:107)
```

is it possible to swipe from a multi column LazyVerticalGrid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't do that with the standard implementation. There isn't really a design pattern where a swipe-to-dismiss makes any sense in a context of a grid.

But you can probably make your own custom implementation, if it's something that you really want to do (but again, beware of the fact that from a user's standpoint, they probably don't expect that functionality to exist there). Instead of a grid, you can use a combination of `LazyColumn` and  a `Row`, and then use `Modifier.swipeable` on each column item.

Alternatively, if you only want to remove each row without giving the user other actions to pick from, you're probably better off just creating a button that gets rid of each row (something like an "X" in the top-right corner of each row)